# debian sudo service mongod status shows failed but mongo is working

Tags: mongodb, debian

I started a replica set with three servers with default port and used a different data directory. But when i did sudo service mongod stop. it said failed. so i went into mongo shell and did a shutdown and mongo shell stopped working. now when i did sudo service mongod start it said failed but i was able to go to mongo shell and the reolica set was working. I checked sudo service mongod status it said failed.

```
sudo service mongod status
[FAIL] Checking status of database: mongod apparently not running failed!
```

i edited mongod.config to have a replica set name , commented out bind_ip, used keyfile for auth. i was working fine before starting a replica set

mongo version 2.6.5.
installed using instructions from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/

The output of `ps ax | grep [m]ongo` is:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: What does the output of `ps ax | grep [m]ongod` show? Please add to your question.

Comment: 1921 ?        Sl     0:08 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: Last question: Do you try to run all three instances on one machine?

Comment: No, i am using three seperate vm instances (one arbiter). all the three instances have this issue. using google compute engine and debian 7

Comment: Ok, then it is most likely that you suffer from the known problem of not well behaving init scripts. Try to add `expect daemon`to `/etc/init/mongod.conf`. This should help.